# How to avoid $_GET browser blocking because of XSS?

Tags: php, xss

I'm palying out with ebay api. Trying to create my "local" xml because it doesn't allow me to read it from remote website because of XSS.

It all works fine if I write complete url to ebay api in file_get_contents() , but if I try to manipulate variables through $_GET it stops working because browser don't allow it. Any idea how could I avoid this? 
This is what I get in firebug

> XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location:
>   moz-nullprincipal:{e9af9927-2754-4959-9d8b-a375737fba40}

Here's the code

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"); 
$a= $_GET["storename"];
$b= $_GET["catnumber"];

echo file_get_contents('http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsIneBayStores&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=APPID&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML&REST-PAYLOAD&storeName='. $a . '&outputSelector=categoryId='. $b);

?>
```

Comment: are you using chrome or safari?

Comment: It doesn't matter it doesn't work in any of them
Here's the xml with parameters 
http://designitive.com/ebayapi.php?storename=Sew%20Lovely%20Patterns&catnumber=307403801

and without parameters it works
http://designitive.com/ebayapi.php

Comment: I have playing with xss about a week ago and chrome/safari blocked to prevent xss atacks...with firefox and IE I could played with it. Soz not helps you.

Comment: what are you saying, that the variables `$a` and `$b` contain Xml?

Comment: no, but the browser detects it and doesn't allow it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.. I had to use urlencode on $_GET

like this

```
urlencode($_GET["storename"]);
```